# SonarQube Securty Advisories

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to locate a web page or alert service that I can sign up for to receive information on security patches / alerts relating to SonarQube.

I need to rate these advisories on a monthly basis to ensure that all security patches are applied in a timely manner.

Regards
Sean

Answer (score 0):

The [downloads page](http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/) lists all the updates. You could just check there once a month.

If you pay SonarSource for support, you could express the desire to receive this information by email as well.

I don't know of any service that lists the info you need. That said, I don't remember seeing a lot of security alerts. It's not like Java where there are quarterly patches.